# How to run db migration when Laravel container is up?

Tags: laravel, docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, docker-registry

I have problem with running db migration on when container is up.

Problems:

- cant set app key because gitlab-ci didn't copy .env file (getting err in gitlab ci console), so setting key needs to happen later
- running migration with wait-for-it because container exits with success code 0 (migrations is up)

I will put code only for my db and web container.

```
db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - my-network

backend:
    image: registry image
    container_name: "backend"
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 1020:80
    networks:
      - my-network
```

gitlab-ci:

```
build-backend:
  tags:
    - vps
  variables:
    GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS: none
  stage: dockerize
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  dependencies: []
  script:
    - docker build -t backend backend
    - cp .env ./backend/.env
    - cd backend
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/backend:$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH .
    - docker tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/backend:$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/frontend:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/backend:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
```

...deploying code

I'm using https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it

Dockerfile:

```
FROM webdevops/php-nginx:7.4-alpine

# Install Laravel framework system requirements (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment#optimizing-configuration-loading)
RUN apk add oniguruma-dev postgresql-dev libxml2-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
        bcmath \
        ctype \
        fileinfo \
        json \
        mbstring \
        pdo_mysql \
        pdo_pgsql \
        tokenizer \
        xml

# Copy Composer binary from the Composer official Docker image
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
ENV WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/html/public
ENV APP_ENV production
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY . .
RUN composer install --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader

RUN chown -R root:root .

RUN chmod -R ugo+rw storage

RUN chmod 777 wait-for-it.sh
RUN chmod 777 migrate.sh
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:3306", "--", "./migrate.sh"]
```

migrate.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

php artisan key:generate
# Optimizing Configuration loading
php artisan config:cache
# Optimizing Route loading
php artisan route:cache
# Optimizing View loading
php artisan view:cache
echo "finished cashes"
php artisan migrate --force &
exec "$@"
```

So how can I solve exit code 0, meant to say how to prevent container from stopping?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use Supervisor which is useful for having all the jobs in background and wont close your container while running migrations.
I can't believe that this configuration from this repo is working perfectly it saves my time. I spent more than 7 days in searching for the best solution, but this guy who posted this saves me!

Refer to this repo please https://github.com/harshalone/laravel-9-production-ready

I didn't have to change a line of code, hope you don't have too. Simply works!

Answer (score 0):

for anyone struggling with running migrations but your database isn't up before your Laravel application, just want to mention that I've used wait-for-it script and changed last line of code in my Dockerfile like this:

```
CMD ["/var/www/docker/wait-for-it.sh", "db:3306", "--", "/var/www/docker/run.sh"]
```

So now my migrations will first wait for database to be up and running.
Just put wait-for-it.sh inside of your docker folder or use it from github directly.